# Why aren't the table headers empty after I delete them?

Tags: c#, wpf

I work with Visual Studio 2019, C# and WPF. I try to delete my tableheader dynamically, but i have some problems.

Problem method description:

I have a method, to select the datapackagename and create a Datatable with them as Datatableheaders. That works so far fine, the problem is to delete the old Headers of the table at the second or third run. I tested some different ways to delete the headers but nothing work for me.

When i use the "First try" (show Problem method) nothing will be deleted, because my tableforDataStream hasn't any columns(watched with debugger at second method run). But when I change tableforDataStream to my DataGrid(dgTable3) I have 3 columns there and I can't add new columns to my tableforDataStream(for example watch last picture left table).

The second and third try are most the same like first try with the exception that I can check if there are some columns left. I have already tried `tableforDataStream.Reset;` but that haven't any sense it's the same solution like "First try"

Problem method:

```
private void CreateOverviewTable_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isConnected != 0)
        {
            //tableforDataStream.Columns.Clear();   <--- First try to delete the old tableforDataStream.Header
            if (dgTable3.Columns.Count != 0)
            {
                while(dgTable3.Columns.Count > 0)
                {
                    //tableforDataStream.Columns.RemoveAt(0);   <--- Second try to delete the old tableforDataStream.Header
                    dgTable3.Columns.RemoveAt(0); //<--- Third try to delete the old tableforDataStream.Header
                }
            }

            int anzZeilen = tableSelectedVar.Rows.Count;
            if (anzZeilen != 0)
            {
                dgTable1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                dgTable3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                //Create an array for the data packages(VarName, SaveAddress, VarSize)
                string[,] inhaltVar = new string[anzZeilen, 3];

                //Copie all infos from the Variable into the array
                for (int i = 0; i <= anzZeilen - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        inhaltVar[i, j] = tableSelectedVar.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                    }
                }

                //Create for every data package a column inside the tableforDataStream
                for (int k = 0; k <= (inhaltVar.GetLength(0) - 1); k++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //insert the VarName as tableforDataStream.Header   
                        tableforDataStream.Columns.Add(inhaltVar[k, 0]);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exc)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The variable was already send to machine");
                    }
                }
                //send Data over UDP to the machine
                if (isConnected == 1)
                {
                    SendDataToMachine(inhaltVar);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please start first the connection");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please insert minimum one Variable for overwatch", null, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please start the conection to machine");
        }
    }
```

This picture show the result of "First try" at the second method run, the red arrows should be deleted and the green arrows should be there.

[image]

That's my GUI when i delete my DataGrid(dgTable3) like in the actual "problem method"

[image]

EDIT: Add more information and insert the new problem method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know, why i can't delete the headers i like it first but i have a workaround if someone have the same problem.

Here my Code:

```
        private void CreateOverviewTable_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isConnected != 0)
        {
            int anzNeueVar = tableSelectedVar.Rows.Count;
            //Überprüft ob eine Variable zur Überwachung ausgewählt wurde
            if (anzNeueVar != 0)
            {
                //Macht das dgTable1 unsichtbar und macht dgTable3 an der Stelle von dgTable1 sichtbar
                dgTable1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                dgTable3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                //Erstellt ein Array welcher in der ersten Splate den Namen hat, in der zweiten die Adresse und in der dritten die Datengröße.
                string[,] inhaltVar = new string[anzNeueVar, 3];
                //Liest die Daten aus der Tabelle in den Array
                for (int i = 0; i <= anzNeueVar - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        inhaltVar[i, j] = tableSelectedVar.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                    }
                }
                string[,] altInhaltVar = new string[anzNeueVar, 3];
                altInhaltVar = inhaltVar;
                int anzAlteVar = dgTable3.Columns.Count;
                //Erstellt eine Spalte für jeden Parameter welcher überwacht werden soll.
                for (int k = 0; k <= (inhaltVar.GetLength(0) - 1); k++)
                {
                    //erster Durchlauf
                    if (anzAlteVar == 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //Erstellt die Columns für jeden Parameter
                            //dgTable3.Columns.Add(inhaltVar[k, 0]);
                            tableforDataStream.Columns.Add(inhaltVar[k, 0]);
                        }
                        catch (Exception exc)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
                        }
                    }
                    //min zweiter Durchlauf
                    else
                    {
                        //wenn zuviele Spalten vorhanden sind werden die übrigen gelöscht
                        if (anzAlteVar > anzNeueVar)
                        {
                            while (dgTable3.Columns.Count() != inhaltVar.GetLength(0))
                            {
                                dgTable3.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
                            }
                        }
                        //wenn zu wenig Spalten vorhanden sind werden neue hinzugefügt 
                        if (anzAlteVar < anzNeueVar)
                        {
                            int zahler = 1;
                            string szahler;

                            for (int j = 0; j <= dgTable3.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                            {
                                szahler = zahler.ToString();
                                dgTable3.Columns[j].Header = szahler;
                                zahler++;
                            }
                            while (dgTable3.Columns.Count() != anzNeueVar)
                            {
                                szahler = zahler.ToString();
                                DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn { Header = szahler};

                                dgTable3.Columns.Add(textColumn);
                                zahler++;
                            }
                        }
                        //übernimmt die neuen Header in das Datagrid
                        for (int i = 0; i <= dgTable3.Columns.Count-1; i++)
                        {
                            dgTable3.Columns[i].Header = inhaltVar[i, 0];
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Schickt die Daten welche in Tabelle tableSelectedVar sind zur Maschine
                if (isConnected == 1)
                {
                    SendDataToMachine(inhaltVar);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Bitte erste die Verbindung herstellen bevor Daten an die Maschine geschickt werden");
                }

                //TestFunktion: Sendet was auch immer im Suchtextfeld steht
                //TestSend();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Bitte mindestens eine Variable zur Ueberwachung bestimmen", null, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Bitte erst eine Verbindung zur Maschine Herstellen");
        }
    }
```

I'll hope someone can use that as workaround, for me it works perfekt friendly wishes sniffi.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the columns from the `DataGrid` or `GridView`:

```
dgTable1.Columns.Clear();
```

Comment: When i delete the Columns from my Datagrid the table hasen't any header's and i can't add some Columns to my table.

Comment: Isn't this what you want? I guess you are auto generating the columns?

Comment: Hi, the Problem is, when i delete the Columns inside the Datagrid i can't add new Columns. My aim is to start the method, all Columns will be deletet inside that Table and i can create new Columns with the new Header. When i make what you write i can't create new Columns.

Comment: What? Of course you can add new columns to `dgTable1.Columns` regardless of how many times you have called the `Clear` method?